# Docx4j removing whitespaces

Tags: java, docx4j

When I have an org.docx4j.wml.Text with only a whitespace it's removed.

```
R createR = wmlObjectFactory.createR();
Text createText2 = wmlObjectFactory.createText();
createText2.setSpace("preserve");
createText2.setValue(" ");
createR.getContent().add(createText2);
p.getContent().add(toAddIndex, createR);
```

The create text value "{space}", isn't added to my docx file even with

> ```
> createText2.setSpace("preserve");
> ```

Comment: Should work.  What does XmlUtils.marshallToString(p) print?

Comment: It prints this: [full xml](http://justpaste.it/qz6p)
(sorry for the link, I didnt know a better way to send full xml)

Comment: I guess it was a Word 2007 bug, opening on any other version or editor, it works perfectly.